# 'Wait for field change in current item' does not fire

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow

We have a SharePoint 2010 workflow which has a command 'Wait for field change in current item'. The workflow runs on document library. The library is being populated by an external job (C# application). The reason we are using 'Wait for field change in current item' is that when the job uploads the document in library it perform two updates - one in which it uploads only the document and seconds when it updates the metadata columns. We wait for information in that metadata column.

But in some cases 'Wait for field change in current item' gets stuck and never gets executed, despite the field for which it is waiting has been populated.

I our development server we are simply unable to reproduce the issue. When we execute job at development server the 'Wait for field change in current item' always works.

Can anyone provide any path where we should be looking at? Is there any server setting that we need to check on development and production to compare?

PS: We are using SharePoint 2010 designer workflow in SharePoint 2013 environment.

Comment: Is it possibility that in Production server, metadata change value execute before Workflow reaches upto "Wait for Field change in current item" activity?

Comment: @Sam: Not sure... But this does make some sense as to why this would fail.

Comment: Need to put log in external job with Date-Time then check whether this metadata update value change before workflow or not?